# SpriteKit GameOverlay

Tags: objective-c, interface, xcode5, sprite-kit, overlay

If 2 objects hit each other, a GameOver layer should appear, but it should be transparent. That means, the whole Game Scene should be showing, with a transparent GameOver and the Score etc. 
I can config. the Scene by myself, but I don't know how to add it in my MyScene.h.

The code for the 2 objects collision :

```
 - (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
```

{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

```
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}

if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & StoneCategory) != 0 &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & HumanCategory) != 0)
{
    // Here should be some code
}
```

}

Comment: you should call a method that create a SKNode bigger than scene, with background black color with alpha, with label score ecc, and add it to scene like: [self addChild:GameOverScene];

Comment: Can you give me an example please, since I am working with Xcode since 2 weeks? So in the // here should be some code I wrote [self GameOver], and made a new void to show the GameOverScene. But it doesn't work

Comment: which means it does not work? more details please

Comment: I createt an SKScene GameOver.h/m and whenever a collision is there it goes to GameOver.m . but that isnt transparent, it is a new Scene as I mentioned. I wanted just an example for your code, since I am really new. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why are you looking to cover the whole screen with a transparent layer? If you just want to display some text like 'game over', the score and other things - why not just add the text as labels?

Comment: Ok, you are prob. right. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface yourScene()
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *scoreMenu;
@end
```

...

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & StoneCategory) != 0 &&
(secondBody.categoryBitMask & HumanCategory) != 0)
{
    self.scoreMenu = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ScoreMenuPicture.png"];
    self.scoreMenu.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),     CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    self.scoreMenu.name = @"scoreMenu";
    self.scoreMenu.yScale = 0.7;
    self.scoreMenu.xScale = 0.5;
    self.scoreMenu.alpha = 0.7;
    [self addChild:self.scoreMenu];
}
```

adjust the y scale, x scale and alpha to your preference accordingly.

Another remedy:
Create a image with any image editing software (gimp etc) with alpha background and add it to the scene